# I need to set background image to echoed <div>

Tags: php, html, sql, styles, echo

Posting background image to echoed div, I fetch name of image I want to use for specific div from database, but when I try to set filepath to background image as you see in the code below it doesn't work, I also tried 
`style='background-image: url('<?php echo $imageLocation; ?>')'`.

So it echoes div but his background isn't changed, i have the right image in folder that I use as my filepath. I will appreciate help,

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {   
        $img = $row['img'];
        define ('SITE_ROOT', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
        $imageLocation = SITE_ROOT."images/articlePics/$img";
        $posts .= "<div  class='newArticle' style='background-image: url('$imageLocation')'></div>";
    }
    echo $posts;
}
```

Comment: I also tried to echo $imageLocation with php in url brackets, but it didnt work.

Comment: Unless `$posts` wasn't already defined, you need to remove the dot in `$posts .= "<div.....`, or add `$posts = "";` above it.

Comment: I alreadi have it defined, it wouldn't post even div if that was a problem...;)

Comment: I posted my answer below.

Comment: I posted my answer about 1/2 hour ago since this comment, and made a few edits to it. I'm not sure if you saw it or not but I've yet to hear from you. If that still fails you and as I stated in my answer, you may have errors somewhere; check for them. There isn't anything I can add to it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, you mentioned that i dont have anything in my div, I actually have, some headers and paragraphs(didn't want to post long code here, I personally don't like when i see long code, but i see I should have at least put some <p> in it, that's my bad), and I additionally styled width and height of newArticle class, so that's not the problem, as soon as I can i will test everything else, again thanks for you answer...;)

Comment: Ok here is an update, i tried everything, and it didn't work, i tried just to echo $imageLocation to see if the path to image is wrong and it wasn't, further I copied what was echoed from $imageLocation and use it to style .newArticle background-image option and it worked, that showed me that path is ok, and the name in db is ok and  that i have picture where it should be, however that's not what i want, because I want to post diferent image for diferent div, thats why I styled background image directly from div, not in css, since all those div's are same class, maybe there is another way?

Comment: I forgot to say that I used what was echoed from $imageLocation to style .newArticle background-image option in CSS and it worked, I don't want to be any confusion.

Comment: Glad to hear it. If you feel that my answer solved or helped the question, consider accepting it. That way this informs the Stack system/members that the question was solved.

Comment: Another update, I tried to see how will the website work in internet explorer, and the code is working there, but it desn't work in Chrome 0.o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either remove the quotes around the variable:

```
url('$imageLocation')
    ^              ^
```

So that it reads as:

```
url($imageLocation)
```

or use escaped double quotes:

```
url(\"$imageLocation\")
```

Sidenote: Do not use `url("$imageLocation")` without escaping the double quotes, since that will throw a parse error.

Both will work. However, I would opt for the latter, being the escaped double quotes which is the method that should be used.

An example as per https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/background-image

```
background-image: url("http://www.example.com/bck.png");
```

- Having looked at the HTML source, it would have revealed a "No space between attributes" message.

If that still fails, you may have syntax errors somewhere.

References:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

---

> *"I also tried `style='background-image: url('<?php echo $imageLocation; ?>')'`"*

If you tried that inside the echo, then that would have thrown a parse error; since you're already in PHP.

Had it been outside of PHP, then the following would have also worked:

```
<?php 
// ...
?>
<body>
    <div style='background-image: url("<?php echo $imageLocation;?>")'></div>
</body>
```

However, since there is nothing inside that div, it won't show you anything really. If you look at the HTML source, you will see the image source is well in fact there. If it isn't, again; you may have errors somewhere.

So you could test that out with some text, and for example:

```
<?php 
// ...
?>
<body>
    <div style='background-image: url("<?php echo $imageLocation;?>")'>Some text</div>
</body>
```

or:

```
<body>
<?php 
$article = "Your article";
?>
<div style='background-image: url("<?php echo $imageLocation;?>")'>
<?php echo $article;?>
</div>
</body>
```